# Kafka streams API - deserialize dynyamically generated JSON

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been trying to find a solution to the following situation with no avail:

I have a Kafka Streams application which should read from a single input topic a series of JSON objects, all not exactly the same as one another. Practically speaking, each JSON is a representation of an HTTP request object, thus not all JSON records have the same headers, request parameters, cookies and so forth. Furthermore, the JSON objects are written

Is there any way to achieve this? Not expecting for any detailed how-to solutions. Only for some leads on how I can achieve this, as my search over the internet has ended me with nothing so far.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea: use [Jackson's tree model](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_460.html) to dynamically parse your JSON into a `JsonNode`, and then use this tree representation in your Kafka Streams topology to process the requests.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
...
```